# How do I troubleshoot Visual Studio which is hanging when loading ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Yesterday I worked on an MVC 3 project in Visual Studio 2010 and then shut down Visual Studio before leaving work.

This morning when I try to load the same project in Visual Studio the project hangs.  I have restarted my computer, disabled all add-ons and extensions that I could.  Still no banana.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.  I would try to clean the solution if I could get it to load but I can't.  (Can I clean the solution from the VS command window?).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  How do I troubleshoot this?

Seth

Comment: You can clean your solution manually by deleting all bin and obj folders within the solution.

Comment: Open a second copy of VS, attach its debugger to the first copy, then hit Pause when it freezes.

Comment: Have you looked for messages in the EventViewer?

Comment: Also Visual Studio Works better when is started with Administrator rights.

Answer (score 8):

You could try starting visual studio from the command line [with logging enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx).

There a several [other switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) available, which may also be useful, like starting in [safemode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)...

Comment: I did this (started with logging) and inexplicably my project has started loading.  I cleaned the solution, enabled all of the extensions and add-ons and the project still loads.   So I am back in business.  But I am not sure what I did that got it going.  I'm just going with it.

Comment: This solution worked for me too (didn't enable logging though)! Another thing that may help is unload (not remove!) all the projects first.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is something unexpected. A wild guess Try [resetting user settings of Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx)

Comment: I fixed it before trying this but I think this is a good suggestion.

Comment: This link is now broken, would you consider updating it?

Answer (score 1):

Close solution, delete your *.suo and open it again.
If issue still persist, do above tip again, clean and rebuild solution, wait while to check whether a pop-up window prompt for logging (azure, sharepoint or something like that).
Enter credential, choose remember.

Hope that help.